# How do I get a parent controls height to adjust dynamically in power platform canvas app?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have a horizontal container, which contains a number of labels with a specific width.  The labels Auto height is turned on, so their height auto adjusts to the content.

My Gallery represents rows in a table, and I'm trying to get the row height to automatically adjust based on the max height of any of the labels inside the row.

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
Flexible Height Gallery (Table)
   Horizontal Container (Row)
      Vertical Container (Multiple lines in each row) 
         Horizontal Container  (Line 1) - Flexible Height Enabled
             Label 1
             Label 2
             ...
         Horizontal Container  (Line 2)- Flexible Height Enabled
             Label 5
```

It seems like the horizontal container that parents the labels can't adjust even thought it has flexible height enabled.

Is it an issue with how the horizontal container is configured, or an issue somewhere up the chain, such as one of the parent containers or the gallery.

Although it's weird, because a flexible height gallery still has a Template Size property which seems to fix each item's height in the gallery to a specific size, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

On your horizonal container - you can set its `Height` property to:

```
Max(Label1.Height, Label2.Height, Label3.Height...) + Self.PaddingTop + Self.PaddingBottom
```

Comment: Oh wow. I recognize this might be the only way, but it is pretty brute force :)

Comment: I'm unaware of any container that grows to accommodates its children (except those that have `Card` as children like Form or scrollable canvas).

Comment: Thanks.   Maybe I have a larger issue.. then?  I figured this would be a common need, but maybe I'm approach this wrong in the first place?  If you are trying to display/edit tabular data, then you are probably using a gallary, which will have repeating rows, and you can have content in the rows that has height that is unknown at design time, you'd need to be able to easily accomodate a dynamic row height.